# Autosar function prototype not recognized by Source insight

Tags: source-insight, autosar

Following is the prototype of function declaration according to Autosar standard:

```
FUNC(Return_Type, Memory_section) Function_Name
(
Input_parameters
);
```

but this is not recognized by [source insight](http://www.sourceinsight.com), what setting should i do to get this issue corrected

Answer (score 0):

In your file C.tom located in \Documents\SourceInsight, add following line:

FUNC(rettype, memclass)  rettype